Relation between spectral norm and Euclidean norm of a matrix
I'm reading [BGG+'Eurocrypt2014] paper and I doubt that maybe there be a typo in
relation between spectral norm and Euclidean norm of a matrix. Here is the part of the paper


I think we must have $\|\mathbf{R}\|_{2}\leq\sqrt{m}\|\mathbf{R}\|$, because according to the definition of the spectral norm, we must calculate the Euclidean norm of vector $\mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}=\sum_{i=1}^{m}x_{i}\cdot\mathbf{r}_{i}$ (for some vector $\|\mathbf{x}\|=1$) where this vector is equal to linear combination of columns of matrix $\mathbf{R}$. The Euclidean norm of a matrix is the Euclidean norm of its largest columns. So $\|\mathbf{r}_{i}\|\leq\|\mathbf{R}\|$ for $i\in[m]$. Finally, we have $\|\mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}\|\leq\sqrt{m}\|\mathbf{R}\|$.
